# Why would we be interested in non-norm metric spaces?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

The axioms for a norm and the distance function for a metric space are very similar. The only difference really is that one of the norm axioms specifies 'absolute scalability' ($||\alpha x|| = |\alpha| \ ||x||$), whereas this is not required for a metric space. So what are the implications of this? Of course, a metric can be induced by a norm..and in this case absolute scalability will be present.

However, what about the case when the metric is not induced by a norm and this absolute scalability property is not present - why would we be interested in such metrics, what are some applications of these? Do the norm-induced metrics constitute only a small subset of the full class of interesting metrics or are they a large portion of this class..and are they really the only ones widely and regularly used in practise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Norms must be introduced in *vector spaces*. A metric can be defined in *any* set, no algebraic operation appears in the three axioms.

Practice. What is practice? As a mathematical analyst I should admit that we mainly work in normed spaces because we nedd *calculus*. Metric spaces are general and clean, but it is hard to make actual computations in them. There are metrics, even in $\mathbb{R}^2$, that are not induced by norms. Whether you want to call them useful, it is a matter of choice.

Anyway, your question could be even extended: since metric spaces are only a small subset of topological spaces, why do we study general topology? The answer is that mathematicians do not stop at the ground floor, they want to reach the first, the second floor and possibly the last foor of the building. This called *generalization*.

Answer (score 1):

Put up your right index finger in the air. The tip of your finger touches a point in space. What is the norm of this point?

Also put up your left index finger in the air. Now you have two points. You have a distance between them, probably between 10 cm and 50 cm.

Thus, the space we live in has a metric, but not a norm.

Comment: Well the Euclidean norm could be said to be the natural norm for the space we live in!

Comment: So, @eurocoder, what is the Euclidean norm of the point at your nosetip?